# Is it possible to define a new statement?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I want to be able to define a statement in javascript. For example, I want to define 
a statement called file that works like a class.

```
function file() {
 //code goes here
}
```

I want that to be used as a statement, like `if`,`for`,and`return`.

```
file filename(filename,purpose) {
 //code goes here
}
```

Do I need to build a seperate compiler or is it possible?
Please change the title if there is a better way to say it.

Comment: No, you can't do this. Look into higher-order functions, specially function decorators. And also check out SweetJS.

Comment: There'd be no point in building a compiler, as javascript is mostly used client-side, so making non-compliant js code wouldn't work unless people use your solution exactly. However, [functions/objects can work](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) [like classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: so in short, you can do `somefile = new file();`

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish?

You can emulate *some* class-like structure in JavaScript using the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript)

Also, I've never seen a class work like what you've described -- typically you instantiate an object of a class, and then access the object's public properties.  This can be done in JavaScript ('cept objects are created dynamically).  For example:

```
// file 'class'
var file = function () {

  var a; // private variable

  function filename(name, purpose) {
    // code goes here 
  }

  // return public members
  return {
    filename: filename
  };
};

// An object created from your 'class' with the member function 'filename()'
var aFile = file();
```

Then call your member function using the `.` operator, like so: `aFile.filename(name, purpose);`

Answer (score 0):

This would be writing a new language based on Javascript, much like Coffeescript, among many others. Those languages need to compile *to* JS before being served to a web browser, for instance.

Take a look at a Coffeescript -> JS interpreter to know how to go about this. For the record, I don't think this is a good approach.

Lastly I'll note that languages like Scala have very good DSL support, meaning it's easy to add features within the language. For instance, even + in Scala is library code, not native code. (More technically, could be written that way from a language standpoint.)

Comment: Javascript can technically do what Scala does. Only the syntax of functions in javascript is a lot more verbose so we end up with a bit more noise and a bit less DSL-looking. Still, there are plenty of DSL-like libraries in javascript for example jQuery and promises (technically not a library but a design pattern). Every time someone comes up with a DSL-like library in javascript whole paradigms gets shifted :)

Comment: @slebetman yeah but they're also somewhat awful precisely because thy're *not* lighter weight DSLs. That verbosity is really awful in promise chains. hence why ecma 6 introduces lambdas, etc. Also generators / yield support can bake in asynchronity a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to define a statement in javascript.
>
> I want that to be used as a statement, like if,for,andreturn.

**No**, you cannot do this, as a Javascript parser would not be able to parse this.

If you really wish to do this, your only option would be to create your own language, and write a transpiler from your new language to Javascript, as @djechlin has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want is to implement control structures rather than statements since the example you gave, `if`, `for` and `return` are control structures. If that is what you really mean then yes, you can do that with functions but not with the syntax you describe.

In javascript, functions are first class objects. That is, they can be assigned to variables and passed as arguments to other functions. For example, here's an implementation of `if` that uses no built-in control structure (no `if`, `while`, `switch` etc. and no ternary operator):

```
function IF (condition, callback) {
    [function(){}, callback][+!!condition]();
}
```

You can use the above function as a replacement of `if` but the syntax is a bit unconventional:

```
IF ( a == b, function(){
    console.log('hello');
});
```

But if you've been programming javascript long enough the above syntax would be familiar and you'd have encountered many similar control structures implemented as functions such as `[].forEach()` and `setTimeout()`.

So, if you want to implement a control structure to parse a file for example, you can do something like this:

```
function parseFile (filename, callback) {
    // code to process filename
    callback(result);
}
```

Or even something like this:

```
function eachLine (filename, callback) {
    // code to process filename
    for (var i=0; i<file_content.length; i++) {
        callback(file_content[i]);
    }
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
eachLine("some_file.txt",function(line){
    if (line.match(/hello/)) {
        console.log('Found hello! This file is friendly.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need parameters you can do:

```js
Object.defineProperty(window, 'newcmd', {
  get: () => console.log("hello")
})

newcmd
```